# CSS - Prevent scrolling but leave the scrollbar

Tags: css

I'm using `overflow:hidden` to prevent the body from scrolling when an overlay is shown. The problem is this removes the scrollbar so the whole page shifts a bit to the right. It shifts again when the overlay is removes and the overflow is set back to auto.

Is there a way to get around this? I would like to freeze the document from scrolling but would like to prevent the page from jumping around.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BCX64/2/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add this:

```
html {
     overflow-y:scroll;
}
```

The `body` element will hide overflow (as you already have it), and the `html` element will just display an empty scroll bar. This works since you happen to have `html` and `body` set at `height:100%`.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BCX64/3/

Alternatively, you can prevent scrolling like this when you show the overlay:

```
// Find current scroll positions
var top = $(window).scrollTop();
var left = $(window).scrollLeft()

$(window).scroll(function(){
    // Force scroll back to original positions
    $(this).scrollTop(top).scrollLeft(left); 
});
```

Then unbind the event when you hide the overlay:

```
$(window).unbind('scroll');
```

You don't need the `noscroll` class in this case.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BCX64/6/

Comment: This kinda works... http://jsfiddle.net/BCX64/5/ If you scroll down a bit then click the button, the page body jumps back to the top.

Comment: Yes, because you have `overflow:hidden` on `body`. I get what you mean though, 1 minute...

Answer (score 0):

What if you create a fake scrolling bar and place it in the right side.. you can customize the design too.

Comment: not all browsers/oses have the same width scroll bar - or any scroll bar at all for that matter.